# ST_ClusterDBSCAN gives all features a cluster

Tags: postgis

I am using ST_ClusterDBSCAN to help cluster some building polygons. I am using the following SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE clusters AS SELECT ogc_fid, cid, wkb_geometry AS geom FROM ( 
    SELECT ogc_fid, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(wkb_geometry, eps := 5, minpoints := 1) over () AS cid, wkb_geometry 
    FROM building) sq;
```

When I check the results every feature has a cid even though there are no other features with the same cid, i.e a building is not within 5 metres of another.

Reading the docs, ST_ClusterDBSCAN should give a feature not within a cluster the value of null.

So I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs for ST_ClusterDBSCAN are incorrect.  The docs state that

> A "core" geometry is within eps distance of at least minpoints other
>   input geometries

The word "other" is incorrect here; each geometry is considered to be within eps distance of itself.

A correct definition is found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN):

> A point p is a core point if at least minPts points are within
>   distance ε(ε is the maximum radius of the neighborhood from p) of it
>   (including p).

If you want to use `minpoints := 1` and remove clusters that have only a single geometry, you can add another layer to your query as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE clusters AS 
SELECT
  ogc_fid, 
  cid, 
  wkb_geometry AS geom
 FROM 
    SELECT
       ogc_fid,
       cid,
       count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY cid) AS num_geoms,
       wkb_geometry 
    FROM ( 
      SELECT
        ogc_fid, 
        ST_ClusterDBSCAN(wkb_geometry, eps := 5, minpoints := 1) over () AS cid, 
        wkb_geometry 
      FROM building
    ) sq
) ssq
WHERE num_geoms > 1;
```

Comment: Have you informed to update the docs? Nice answer

Comment: @dbaston thanks. that works brilliantly. It is significantly quicker using those sub queries. Also been using your blog post, so thanks for that too

Comment: @JohnBarça, I committed a fix to the docs, but it takes a while to show up on the site.